# Auto initialization of structure in STL list

Tags: c++, list, struct, stl

Is the following method of adding structures to the list valid?

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

struct TabState
{
  TabState( int p ):
    a(p),
    b(2),
    c(55),
    d(453),
    e(25521)
  {}
  int a,b,c,d,e;
};
std::list<TabState> m_tabs;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    m_tabs.push_back(77);
    std::list<TabState>::iterator iter;

    for(iter = m_tabs.begin(); iter != m_tabs.end(); ++iter)
    {
        TabState test = *iter;
        std::cout <<
            test.a << "\n" <<
            test.b << "\n" <<
            test.c << "\n" <<
            test.d << "\n" <<
            test.e << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Does the push_back() function always create an instance automatically? If so, does it obviate the need to manually create a structure instance before pushing it into the list?

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem... Do you get an unwanted output ? A compilation error ?

Comment: I'm having no problems as such. I just wanted to verify if such a statement is correct or not, cause I haven't been able to find such examples on Google. Also, is there a name given to this particular way of initializing the structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that is happening here is implicit conversion.

- `m_tabs.push_back` is expecting a `TabState`, or something convertable to one.
- `TabState` has a one argument constructor taking an int that isn't marked as `explicit`, meaning it allows implicit conversion from an `int` to a `TabState`.

So `m_tabs.push_back(77)` is implicitly converting the `int` to a `TabState`. This will happen with any function expecting a `TabState`, not just `push_back`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the following method of adding structures to the list valid?

I see nothing invalid in the code.

> Does the push_back() function always create an instance automatically?

Yes.

> If so, does it obviate the need to manually create a structure instance before pushing it into the list?

With `push_back` no, it does not. You do need to pass an object to it. That's because `push_back` creates the new instance by copying or moving from the function parameter. That's what you've done actually. `TabState` has a non-explicit constructor that takes an `int`, so when you pass an `int` to `push_back` which expects `TabState` or `TabState&&`, then the passed `int` will be implicitly converted to a `TabState` using that constructor. That temporary object will be passed to `push_back`.

However, there is `emplace_back` which forwards the arguments to the constructor directly, so there are no intermediate objects.

Comment: The temporary generated by the implicit conversion is probably an R value, so the result will probably be just as efficient as `emplace_back`.

Comment: Not probably, it is an rvalue.

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote works and is correct, but there are some comments:

Make the constructor explicit. You are actually initializing a `TabState` with an `int`, and not convert an `int` to `TabState`.

```
struct TabState
{
  explicit TabState( int p ):
...
  {}
...

m_tabs.push_back(TabState(77));
```

Unless really, *really* necessary, don't use `std::list`. Use `std::vector` instead, it is more efficient in most cases.

You can declare the iterator inside the `for` header. Or, if your compiler supports C++11, use range based for.

```
for(std::list<TabState>::iterator iter = m_tabs.begin(); iter != m_tabs.end(); ++iter)
```

or

```
for(const TabState& element : m_tabs)
```